# mod(3^146, 293) among others returning the same incorrect values in Matlab and JS

Tags: javascript, matlab, modulo

First note that `mod(3^146, 293) = 292`.
But inputting `mod(3^146, 293)` in Matlab returns 275.
Inputting `Math.pow(3,146) % 293` in JS returns 275.
This same error occurs (as far as I can tell) every time.

What is the obvious thing that I am missing here?

Comment: I find it hard to see how `mod(3^146,293)=292` is true

Comment: One can check on multiple online calculators. Also, since 293 is prime, you can arrive at this result via Legendre's symbol, which is equivalent to 3^146=3^(292/2) modulo 293.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/52738), MATLAB uses double-precision floating point numbers by default, which have limits on their resolution (i.e. the floating point relative accuracy, [`eps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)). For example:

```
>> a = 3^146

a =

     4.567759074507741e+69

>> eps(a)

ans =

     7.662477704329444e+53
```

In this case, 3<sup>146</sup> is on the order of 10<sup>69</sup> and the relative accuracy is on the order of 10<sup>53</sup>. With only 16 digits of precision, a double can't store the exact integer representation of an arbitrary 70 digit integer.

An alternative in MATLAB is to use the [Symbolic Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html) to create symbolic numbers with a greater resolution. This gives you the answer you expect:

```
>> a = sym('3^146')

a =

4567759074507740406477787437675267212178680251724974985372646979033929

>> mod(a, 293)

ans =

292
```

Answer (score 2):

in JavaScript, `Math.pow(3, 146)` is larger than the constant `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is the upper limit of numbers that can be represented without losing any accuracy. Therefore JavaScript cannot accurately represent `Math.pow(3, 146)` within the 64 bit limit.

MATLAB also has limits on its integer size but can represent a large number with the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

There are also [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) that you can implement to accomplish this without overflowing.

Comment: The handy infinite precision calculator dc let's me know that 3 ^ 146 is 4567759074507740406477787437675267212178680251724974985372646979033929.

Answer (score 0):

I've skipped a few steps by pre-computing that `3 ^ 30` is a good location to pivot, since

```
3^30 % 293 ==> 15
```

leaving plenty room in 64-bit floating point to exponentiate before running into precision issues. Hope this illustrates how one can perform that modulo operation in a reasonably short equation without any bigint add-ons

*conceptually it's the same even though this isn't Javascript*:

```
 expn ::
         146
 base ::   
           3
 modp :: 
         293
b^e%m :: 
         292


1 print "\texpn :: ",   (____ = (_+=_^=_<_) + _^_^_ * (__ = ++_*_))
1 print "\tbase ::   ", (_)
1 print "\tmodp :: ",     ___ = (__ += _--) * (__ += __) + _ + ++_
1 print "\tb^e%m :: ",(_^(__ += _+_) % ___) ^ (_____ = int(____/__) \
                                   ) % ___ * _^(____ - __ * _____) % ___
```

PS: turns out `3 ^ 29` is optimal, because it can skip one extra modulo:

```
( 3^29 % 293 ) ^ floor( 146 / 29 ) * 3 % 293 ==> 292
```

============

Rationale for trying to locate a regional minimum :

These are powers of 187, agaianst prime modulus `4,880,808,090,089`

```
1  187            9   469329112592   17  4523139689563  25  118376423187
2  34969          10  4790806523191  18  1447322362884  26  2613158775613
3  6539203        11  2692939350430  19  2204836904413  27  579882030731
4  1222830961     12  856425251243   20  2316621557755  28  1060161764739

5  228669389707   13  3965663099593  21  3697119372353  29  3017926402633
6  3714711154497  14  4576978020452  22  3167381927462  30  3059306932136
7  1576237098301  15  1753474058949  23  1722641534625  31  1035849769019
```

`8  1907851976947  16  885506987500`     **`24  633029001`**          `32  3352391293082`

While it's not always feasible to quickly find sudden dip like this one, but when they do show up, it's likely to be advantageous to re-pivot the exponentiation to be from ::

```
( 187 ^ 24 % 4880808090089 ) ^ floor( original-exponent / 24 )
```

then pad back

```
 187 ^ ( original-exponent % 24 ) % 4880808090089
```

This ties back to the original question - I listed `3 ^ 29` because it's a very small local minimum of just `5` after modulation - the equation got simplified even quicker than the standard `pow-mod()` algorithm of nonstop squaring - the residual task has been rapidly reduced down to just this ::

```
   5^floor( 146 / 29 ) * 3^( 146 % 29 ) % 293
=  5^5                 * 3^(1)          % 293
=  5^5 * 3 % 293
=  292
```

Because `5` is just so tiny, now we can jump the exponent all the way to `3 ^ 638`

```
29 * 22 = 638
```

instead of having to do

```
25313984575877800498658462583800985577974442039603115135745173
18462307644190952769606496119812701201786581976576370098736741
18722732359264456878773248561111529530810447657351164612632519
16930665382479525619938398262413224836488826714294577607853696
062994625347787942966705881668972755048655535624173740089 % 293
```

now it's just

```
            5 ^ 22 % 293

= 2384185791015625 % 293

= 145
```

something that can done entirely within double-precision floating point

Comment: I don't understand what is in the bigger code block. Is that a programming language, or some notation? Maybe you can explain a bit better what you're doing there.

Comment: @CrisLuengo : that's `POSIX`-complaint `awk` code. The only difference between that and javascript is that exponentiation is `^` instead of `**`. `awk` can directly accept the output of boolean operators (like `< less than`) as an integer of `0 / 1` instead of requiring another layer of type casting